EF Core migrations: updating database with previous migration existing in __EFMigrationsHistory table but not in .NET project
I'd like to update a shared dev database with my latest migrations.  However, I see someone has applied new migrations from a different branch. Those migrations appear in the __EFMIgrationsHistory table in the shared database, but not in my .NET & EF Core project.
What will happen if I attempt to update the database with my migrations?
Given the other migrations don't exist in my .NET & EF Core project attempting to apply my changes won't roll back theirs. But will it remove the records of their migrations from the __EFMigrationsHistory table (thereby causing them problems the next time they attempt to update the database)? Or perhaps crash and burn when I attempt to update the database?
Given the database is shared between 6 dev teams I'm a bit reluctant to experiment, in case I break things for others.

Rollback your migrations and generate again. Otherwise you may have conflicts.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv, the problem is that the other migrations don't exist in the .NET EF Core project (I've just verified they don't exist in the repo at all, on any branch).  The only record of their existence is in the __EFMigrationsHistory table.

If database is not damaged, this additional record should not break migrations.

Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv.  I've now tested my up and down migrations.  I can confirm that those additional records in the __EFMigrationsHistory table were retained following both my up and down migrations, and that both the up and down migrations succeeded without error.
